# Extract month and day from linux "date" command

Tags: linux, shell, date

I would like to modify the following statement to extract the Month, as well as day:

> testdate=$(date -d "2 days" +%d| sed 's/0([1-9])/ \1/')

right now it only extracts the day...

I'm currently googling how sed works.  looks like a regular expression of sorts that's being used but... I thought I'd check with the forum for certain.

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

now I have:

```
  testdate=$(date -d "2 days" "+%b %_d %Y")
```

Which is great... except when the leading zeros in the day are stripped out.  then i end up with two spaces between the Month and day
for example, for April 29, 2014, I get:

```
  Apr 29 2014
```

which is great.  But for May 01, 2014 I get:

```
  May  1, 2014
```

where there's a double space between "May" and "1".  I guess i can do it in two steps... by doing the date command, followed by sed to find and replace double spaces. 
Just wondering if there's a way to do it all in one command. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To read the month and day into shell variables (assuming bash/ksh/zsh)

```
read month day < <(date -d "2 days" "+%m %d")
```

If you're planning to do arithmetic on these values, be of  numbers that would be treated as octal but are invalid octal numbers `08` and `09`. If you want to strip off the leading zero, use `"+%_m %_d"`

---

Using `read`, the shell takes care of the excess whitespace for you:

```
read mon day year < <(date -d "2 days" "+%b %_d %Y")
testdate="$mon $day $year"
```

If you don't want to use the temp vars:

```
testdate="Apr  5 2014"       # $(date -d "2 days" "+%b %_d %Y")
testdate=${testdate//  / }   # globally replace 2 spaces with 1 space
echo "$testdate"
```

Comment: glenn, how do you change your code to prevent double spaces in between month and day when the leading zero in days have been stripped off?  Other than that, your code is perfect!

Comment: Please see my EDIT 1 where I try to explain what I'm after.  Thanks!

Comment: Why does the month need leading zero's stripped off, as in `"+%_m %_d"`? Also, perhaps it would be an idea to word the use of `//  / ` as an alternative to `read`, instead of an alternative to using temp vars.

Comment: @user66001, explanation by demonstration: try this at a bash prompt: `echo $((08+1))`

Comment: That produces the error `-bash: 08: value too great for base (error token is "08")` for me, but just realised my first point is null (`%m` used instead of `%b`). Second point should still be valid, however.

Answer (score 8):

[`date`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?date) accepts a `FORMAT` arg which should be used here. `sed` is not necessary:

```
date +%d.%m.
```

Outputs:

```
03.04.
```

in European time format. If you want the month's name printed use

```
date +'%d. %B'
```

Output:

```
03. April
```

Comment: hek2mgl - Use  `<!-- language-all: lang-none -->` in your answer to prevent "April" being highlighted.

Answer (score 2):

For date format `%d` would print only the day.  It's unlikely to extract month unless you specify that in the format.

Specify the format for obtaining the month too.

```
   %b     locale's abbreviated month name (e.g., Jan)
   %B     locale's full month name (e.g., January)
   %m     month (01..12)
```

For example:

```
$ date -d "2 days" +%d/%b
05/Apr
$ date -d "2 days" +%d/%B
05/April
$ date -d "2 days" +%d/%m
05/04
```

Comment: yeah... i see that now ... makes sense.  thanks.  I'm just new to bash programming and didn't even notice the %d till now.

Comment: @dot I'm not sure what your question is.  I've added a few examples.  Let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: devnull, sorry... i was going to post an edit but then i ended up figuring it out.  thanks so much for the help!!  +1. I was actually looking to combine the sed command and the date command - needed to strip out the leading zeros.  which is why i selected glenn jackman's answer.  but thanks again!

Comment: devnull - Use `<!-- language-all: lang-none -->` in your answer to prevent "January", "Apr" & "April" being highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

Seems there is a simpler way to extract [the] month and day from [the] linux “date” command, then all the previous answers.

From `$ date --help`:

```
  By default, date pads numeric fields with zeroes.
  The following optional flags may follow `%':

  -  (hyphen) do not pad the field
```

Which gives us the below, without the use of `sed` or `read` to remove any kind of padding:

`testdate=$(date -d "3 days" "+%b %-d %Y")` (`days` adjusted to show single-digit day number, from today's date)

And outputs the below:

```
$ echo $testdate
Sep 1 2014
```